# Бинарное дерево для хранения слов из букв

Tags: c++, python, binary, дерево

Нужно написать дерево, которое хранило бы в ячейках символы из слов, которые были добавлены.

Задание звучит так: Хранение и распознавания слов на основе бинарного дерева. интерфейс основного класса должен содержать методы для добавления и распознавания указанного слова. Каждый узел дерева представляет собой объект, содержащий определенный символ, и ссылки на две ветви Left и Right. переход по ветви Left осуществляется если текущий символ строке распознаваемого совпадает с символом хранящейся в данном узле дерева. если символы не совпали осуществляется переход по ветке Right.

Вот нашел решение на python https://gist.github.com/zed/b2af40d17fec628ee82df16ba69eecbf , но не могу его переписать на С++, если кто-может, мне хотя бы сделать метод для добавления слов в дерево, дальше разберусь

Comment: смысль  заданий  заключается в том, чтобы вы научились самостоятельно написать  программы, решать задачи, проверить уровень своих знаний,  познавать что то новое,  вспоминать забытое старое и практически применять свои знания. Если вы откуда то перепишете, и кто еще переведет для вас или напишет за вас, то  смысль заданий  пропадет.  И как думаете, зачем нужно кому то сделать за вас?    Тут нет таких услуг,  вы не туда обратились

Comment: Я это прекрасно понимаю, могу кинуть код, того что у меня получилось, я же в вопросе попросил не всю программу, а только функцию добавления буквы. В интернете я подобной задачи не находил, находил только на бинарное дерево слов, или чисел, эти деревья сам прекрасно могу реализовать, я понимаю как оно работает, но вот с бинарным деревом для букв у меня возникли проблемы

Answer (score 0):

В чём проблема? Храните

```
struct Node {
   char symbol;
   Node* left;
   Node* right;
}
```

Когда добавляете, проверяете те условия, которые у вас сказаны:

```
if (node->symbol == symbol)
    node = node->left;
else 
    node = node->right;
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что такая реализация неправильно добавляет буквы в бинарное дерево, подразумевается, что если символы совпали, то просто осуществляется переход дальше по ветке, а не добавление снова этого символа

Comment: @Maxim тут нет никакого добавления. `node` - это текущая рассматриваемая вершина в рекурсивном обходе дерева

Comment: а не могли бы вы написать, если конечно вы не заняты, функцию для добавления бквы(слова) в дерево

Answer (score 0):

вот я сделал функцию для добавления

```
    void add(Tree*& t, char word) {
    if (t == NULL) {
        t = new Tree(word);
        t->left = t->right = NULL;
    }
    else {
        if (word == t->key) {
            t = t->left;
        }
        else {
            t = t->right;
        }
        add(t, word);
    }
}
```

Что в ней не так, подскажите

Comment: У вас нет перемещения по символам слова. Я думаю, что на каждом шаге влево, вы должны брать для сравнения следующий символ. Если текущий символ не совпал и правого линка нет, то нужно создать его и далее построить из всех оставшихся символов список узлов, двигаясь все время (создавая новые узлы) по левым линкам (т.о. вы добавляете в дерево  "хвост" нового слова). Т.е. все узлы при проходе только по правым линкам будут содержать первую букву всех слов, которые начинаются с разных букв. И т.д.